# IBM MobileFirst: How to make app Receive push notification on any activity

Tags: android, push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

I am using Android native MFP sdk. I am trying to implement push notifications.

As per the doc MFP is asking to put

```
<activity
        android:name=".controllers.activities.MyActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.mypackage.NOTIFICATION" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

I am binding the NOTIFICATION intent filter to a activity.

The issue is I have atleast 10 activities in my android app and When my app is in foreground i receive a push onmessage method is called i can get the notification into app.

When my app goes to background and I get a push notification then thats a issue. I launch my app with the above activity but i move on to different activities then i send my app to background now if i get a push notification it lands in the notification bar until now everything works fine. But when i click on the notification it bring my app to foreground and goes to the above mentioned activity MyActivity and kills the presents activity.

Can some body tell me how do i stop this happening i want it to stay on the activity it is and still receive the push.

I know i can use service to receive it but the Mobilefirst is not allowing me to edit the broadcast and service that is already defined in the Mobilefirst sdk.

How do i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got some solution.

I have created a dummy activity and binding the above mention code to it.`

```
<activity
    android:name=".controllers.activities.DummyActivity"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">


    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.mypackage.NOTIFICATION" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

If my app is in background and app gets a notification . On clicking of Notification it will open the dummyactivity and i am calling finish() method in the onResume(). So this particular activity will be finished even before it is opened which will open the pervious activity and I am putting a check saying applaunched if it is false, I am relaunching the app.

This cant be a straight solution but it is a work around for now.